# Trigonometry simplification with $\cos(\alpha)$

Tags: trigonometry

I need help writing this in the trigonometric language
$$
\frac{\cos(\alpha)-i\sin(\alpha)}{\sin\left(\alpha-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+i\sin(π-\alpha)}.
$$
My biggest doubt is simplifying $\cos(\alpha)-i\sin(\alpha)$. I have been told that I can't write it like $\cos(-\alpha)$. I don't know why. Anyone know how to help?

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\sin(\alpha-\pi/2)=-\sin(\pi/2-\alpha)=-\cos\alpha
$$
and $\sin(\pi-\alpha)=\sin\alpha$, so the fraction is
$$
\frac{\cos\alpha-i\sin\alpha}{-\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha}
$$

If you're compelled to use $\operatorname{cis}$, you can observe that
$$
\sin(\alpha-\pi/2)=\sin(\pi/2+\alpha-\pi)=\cos(\pi-\alpha)
$$
so the fraction is
$$
\frac{\operatorname{cis}(-\alpha)}{\operatorname{cis}(\pi-\alpha)}
=\operatorname{cis}(-\alpha-\pi+\alpha)=\operatorname{cis}(-\pi)=
\operatorname{cis}(-\pi+2\pi)=\operatorname{cis}\pi=-1
$$

Comment: Thank you, I have understood that part. But I have to simplify the whole fraction. I think the final result is cis(0π).

Comment: @SarahJones I added the argument with cis,  but it's a sledgehammer.